# Create identical custom product options for thousands of products

Tags: magento2, custom-options, downloadable

I'm trying to recreate a custom image licensing site with Magento 2 and needs some advice in the proper way to structure the image license calculator. I need to recreate the functionality of the existing site like [this page](https://www.goodsalt.com/cart/calculator_kacas0405.html). Essentially this is several custom product options that affect the price of a downloadable product. The main difference is every option in the calculator applies to every product on the site. Also most options are dependent on which parent option is selected.

My question is how should I go about implementing this in Magento? I am very experienced with PHP development but not with Magento. My first inclination is to create a custom Modal with all the usages and how they affect the price than backend page for the CRUD operations on this modal. Then some sort of front end page which would read the options form the model and build the price that way.

Actually seems like a lot of work so I'd be very interested in existing modules paid or free that can do similar things. I'd also be very interested in which specific classes to extend to calculate the price and record the options in the cart. Also an example of a simple CRUD page for a custom module which uses Magento's UI and form components would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: This blog can help you create dependent options [https://www.itoris.com/blog/magento-2-extensions/how-to-create-dependent-custom-options-in-magento-2.html](https://www.itoris.com/blog/magento-2-extensions/how-to-create-dependent-custom-options-in-magento-2.html)